# Recursive formula for integration by parts of given functions

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I need to find, if it actually exists, a recursive formula for the following evaluations of indefinite integrals: 
\begin{align}
I_{1,n}(x,R) &= \underset{n \,\text{terms}}{\underbrace{\int dx \cdots \int dx}}  \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}\\
I_{2,n}(x,R) &= \underset{n \,\text{terms}}{\underbrace{\int dx \cdots \int dx}}  \frac{R^2}{\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}\\
I_{3,n}(x,R) &= \underset{n \,\text{terms}}{\underbrace{\int dx \cdots \int dx}}  \frac{R^2}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}\\
I_{4,n}(x,R) &= \underset{n \,\text{terms}}{\underbrace{\int dx \cdots \int dx}}  \frac{3 R^2 - 2 x^2}{x^2\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}
\end{align}

I am using these formulas in my code and I would like, instead of calculating a large set of integrations analytically, to have some recursive formula for this so I can (possibly) write more efficient code. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with
$$ G_n(x) = \int \dfrac{x^n\; dx}{\sqrt{x^2 - R^2}}$$
I'm always going to omit the $+C$ for simplicity.
We have 
$$ \eqalign{ G_0(x) &= \ln\left(x + \sqrt{x^2-R^2}\right)\cr
G_1(x) &= \sqrt{x^2 - R^2}\cr
G_{n+2}(x) &= \dfrac{n+1}{n+2} R^2 G_n(x) + \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+2} \sqrt{x^2 - R^2} }$$

Now let's take $F_0(x) = \dfrac{x^k}{\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}$ and
$$ \eqalign{F_{n+1}(x) &= \int F_n(x)\; dx = x F_n(x) - \int x F_n'(x) \; dx\cr
&= x F_n(x) - \int x F_{n-1}(x)\; dx} $$
By repeated integrations by parts we get
$$ \eqalign{F_n(x) &= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+1} x^j}{j!} F_{n-j}(x) - \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!} \int x^{n-1} F_0(x)\; dx\cr
&= \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+1} x^j}{j!} F_{n-j}(x) + \dfrac{(-1)^n}{(n-1)!} G_{n-1+k}(x)} $$

EDIT: Hmm, it looks like there may be a simpler recurrence.  I think that
(again with $F_0(x) = \dfrac{x^k}{\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}$, where $k$ is a nonnegative integer) for $n \ge 1$ we have

$$F_n(x) = p_n(x) \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-R^2}) + q_n(x) \sqrt{x^2-R^2}$$
where $p_n$ and $q_n$ are polynomials.  If $k$ is odd, $p_1 = 0$, $p_n$ for $n > 1$ has degree $n-2$, while if $k$ is even, $p_n$ has degree $n-1$;
in either case $q_n$ has degree $n+k-1$, and $p_n$ and $q_n$ are either even polynomials or odd polynomials depending on their degrees.
We can get the coefficients by writing

$$F_n'(x) = p_n'(x) \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-R^2}) + \dfrac{q_n'(x)(x^2-R^2) + p_n(x) + x q_n(x) }{\sqrt{x^2-R^2}}$$

and solving a system of linear equations coming from $F_n' = F_{n-1}$.

For example, with $k=1$ (i.e. your $I_{1,n}$) we have
$$\eqalign{p_1 = 0, & q_1 = 1\cr
           p_2 = -R^2/2, & q_2 = x/2\cr
           p_3 = -R^2 x/2, & q_3 = x^2/6 + R^2/3\cr
           p_4 = -R^2 x^2/4 - R^4/16, & q_4 = x^3/24 + 13 R^2 x/48\cr
           p_5 = -R^2 x^3/12 - R^4 x/16, & q_5 = x^4/120 + 83 R^2 x^2/720 + R^4/45}$$

EDIT:  Hmmm, it looks like in this case the $p_n$ have generating function
$- R t e^{xt} I_1(R t)$ where $I_1$ is a modified Bessel function.
That corresponds to the recurrence equation

$$ (x^2 - R^2) p_{n+1} - (2n + 3) x\; p_{n+2} + (n^2 + 4 n + 3) p_{n+3} = 0 $$

I don't know a generating function or recurrence for the $q_n$.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you SO much @Robert Israel !!!

Comment: once more thank you for the help. Can I please ask if you could propose some material/notes that can help me understand/solve similar problems? Again thanks!